# How can I get the charset of a string/buffer?

Tags: emacs, character-encoding

I need an elisp function that guesses the charset of some html, and since Emacs already does that when opening a file, I wonder if I can reuse it somehow, perhaps by writing the string in a temporary buffer, setting the correct charset, and getting it. Are there such functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [detect-coding-string](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Lisp-and-Coding-Systems.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Emacs has something built-in to guess a character encoding, but it can read character encoding hints in files like -*- coding: utf8 -*- and etc. You can take a look at this [external library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/unicad) though. I guess that you're using some web browser for Emacs like W3M and probably it has something to deal with character encodings based on the http metainformation it receives. [This article](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_encoding_decoding_faq.html) might also be of some help.